# Code Lens Toggle Shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

I totally dig the new code lens stuff in VS2013 but I feel it is to intrusive and would like to be able to toggle it on and off with my keyboard. I was wondering if anyone knows of a shortcut or an extension that will allow me to toggle it on and off? I have searched google and some forums but I am unable to find anything. I am assuming this does not exist yet since I have 0 results but I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 4):

There's no shortcut for it at this stage, and you can't assign one in the VS keyboard options. I suggest people [vote for this feature](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4246480-add-shortcut-to-quickly-open-close-codelens-func) on the Visual Studio User Voice site.