# VSCode: Keyboard shortcuts for modifying user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like the idea of CodeLens, VSCode's plugin that tells you reference counts on all your functions & variables. However, when I'm scanning code, the extra vertical margin added to include the "X references" line annoys me enough that I've disabled it. This is a shame, because it's useful information.

I'd like to be able to control whether CodeLens is active via keyboard shortcut. There seem to be no "editor.action.toggleCodeLens" in the keybindings, though, and trying

`{ "key": "ctrl+l", "command": "editor.codeLens = false" }`

or

`{ "key": "ctrl+l", "command": "editor.codeLens = !editor.codeLens" }`

produces the error `command 'editor.codeLens = false' not found`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Lens Toggle Shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466475/code-lens-toggle-shortcut)

Comment: I created an extension called [Setting Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle) which lets me turn the codeLens on and off easily. My extension also lets you toggle up to 3 VS Code settings. You can then assign the "Setting Toggle" command to a keybinding by opening "Keyboard shortcuts".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this extensions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle

It allows you to setup custom keybindings to toggle any VSCode setting