# hide application title in vscode full screen with default custom window: title bar style

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was looking at full-screen hide-all options in vscode, and observed that hiding the top title bar only works if switching to 'native' windos title bar style.

Is this the only way to do this?

I was also looking at Activity Bar Position (preferably Top) but think the option is n/a when the native Title Bar Style is active (setting id: window.titleBarStyle)

If you do have to use native to hide title bar, is it possible to make a custom toggle action 'macro', that silently switches between modes, including the app.restart if needed?

related (Closed) conversation
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56127

Answer (score 0):

The title bar will still be shown in fullscreen mode if you enable the Command Center (and it's enabled by default). If you want it to be gone in fullscreen mode, I'm pretty sure you need to disable the Command Center (`"window.commandCenter": false,`).

VS Code doesn't have a keyboard shortcut for toggling boolean settings at the time of this writing. See [VSCode: Keyboard shortcuts for modifying user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40472351/11107541) (you do it with extensions). Then you could combine that with [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands). You may or may not find the `isFullscreen` context key useful.